# How to edit/format/change date forat sequence of a existing data into another date format sequence?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates, date

I got a bank account statement xls sheet with date in format of *DD/MM/YYYY* i.e. **06/01/2019** in the original form, but when I'm trying to format it into DD-MON-YY it is taking the value as *MM/DD/YYYY*  and converting it as **1-Jun-2019**.

I have downloaded the file directly from bank server(online bank account) in xls format and opening it in Google Sheet.

Comment: Please, say us what is the alignment of those dates within their cells.
(If it is on the right, then they are true dates; if it's on the left, then google has interpreted them as text)

Comment: Hi Phil, [welcome to Web App Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour)! I think this might be one of the following problems: locale, formatting, or xls. Would it be possible for you to give us a link with cleaned data to help us help you effectively.

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data.

Comment: @Daniele The dates were aligned left of the cells.

Comment: so they are not dates... but text

Comment: Hey @DavidTan Sure I can share it, any anonymous way to share it? And yes it was due to locale, by changing it to my locale, i was able to format the dates vis _Format>Number>Date_. I had to change the locale setting via _File>Settings>Locale_ for each and every file. Is there any way to make it as my default setting?

Comment: @doubleunary How to share it anonymously? Is there any way to share it publicly  but anonymously?

Comment: @Daniele I can't say they were not dates because after changing my locale setting, and then formatting it as date, it worked properly. **06/01/2019** formatted as **6-Jan-2019** rather than **1-June-2019**, like earlier when I posted this thread.

Comment: of course... importing in a sheet with those settings will solve your problem (and the dates will align to right :) )

Comment: @PhilOssefer to share anonymously, use the [Blank Sheet Maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform).